# preserving user authentication for customAPI calls of azure mobile services

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using AzureMobileServices custom API in my hybrid app. The customAPI name is lets say 'userUtils'.
The login and authentication part works good, I am able to authenticate user using facebook/google oAuth.
After login, in its done function , I call a customAPI function - insert (a http POST) - that basically adds  the user in docDB if not already added. and returns back user details to my js client.
(I've 'POST' permission set to 'users with application key' for this customAPI ( btw, is this permission setting right or should it be 'only authenticated users'?)).

```
        //below code is part of a typescript file
        this._zumoClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient( "https://abcdefExample.azure-mobile.net/", "someExampleApplicationKey");
        ... 
        ....    

        ....    
        public authenicateUser(p_oAuthProvider: string) {
            var p: Promise<any> = new Promise(
                (resolve: (result: any) => void, reject: (err: any) => void) =>
                    this._zumoClient.login(p_oAuthProvider, null).done(
                        (loginResult) => {
                            console.log("login returned with result : " + loginResult.userId);
                            var theUserAuthId = loginResult.userId;

                            this._zumoClient.invokeApi('UserUtils/insert', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                body: { userAuthId: theUserAuthId }
                            })
                                .done(
                                (loginResult: any) => {
                                    resolve(loginResult)
                                },
                                (loginErr: any) => {
                                        reject(loginErr);
                                }
                                );
                        },
                        (loginErr: any) => {
                            reject(loginErr);
                        }
                    )
            );

            return p;
        }
```

this first 'invokeAPI' call to my customAPI works good.

However, at a later point, I try to call another customAPI 'usersSocialContacts' (a http GET), I get 401 - 'unauthorized request' ( I've 'get' permission set to 'only authenticated users' for this customAPI).

```
public getUserSocialContacts() {
    var p: Promise<any> = new Promise(
        (resolve: (result: any) => void, reject: (err: any) => void) =>
            this._zumoClient.invokeApi('UserUtils/userSocialContacts', {
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .done(
                (contactsResult: any) => {
                    console.log("got contacts -" + JSON.stringify(contactsResult));
                    resolve(contactsResult);
                },
                (contatcsErr: any) => {
                    reject(contatcsErr);
                }
            )


    );

    return p;
}
```

And if I set the GET permission for this customAPI to 'allow users with the Application key', then the api function gets called but the request.user is undefined.

How does this work, how do I let the customAPI let know that this user has been authenticated and pass the user in every request, from js client. I read some suggestions in some SO questions or otherwise in google search, to cache the user's auth token and pass it in every request to zumo services using an optional filter object in login call, found some examples for C#/.net, but didn't find any clear example or documentation for javascript client, maybe I missed. Azure documentation gives a js example of calling a customAPI from js client, but that doesn't show caching part and sending authenticated user in subsequent requests.

Would appreciate any knowledge sharing or any pointers to right documentation in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like only logged in users to access the custom api, then you need to set the permission to 'only authenticated users'.

Once the user is logged in, if you are using the same instance of MobileServiceClient (without logging out) then any requests made to zumo service should contain zumo auth token.

Comment: as mentioned in my question, I've tried with both 'only authenticated users' and ''allow users with the Application key' permissions for my customAPI. What worked for me is setting userId and accessTokens peoperties of zumo clinet to loginResult.userId and loginResult.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken respectively, in the login's success callback.